# How can I access a SharePoint 2019 site via a UNC?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

we are in the process of upgrading to Sharepoint 2019 from 2013.

sharepoint 2013 was setup by some old employees.

I am trying to find out how to access sharepoint 2019 by UNC.

So far I failed to get access.

with Sharepoint 2013, we can access it using say

UNC path to access - `\\apple.fruits.com\All Plants Names\AllReports\`

but with sharepoint 2019 it failed and give error like "window cannot access..."

Just to note:

Testing is done on user end.
No mapping is done for both sharepoint version.

If I do mapping, I am able to see and access with the word @SSL\DavWWWRoot in the UNC path.

UNC path to access -

```
\\apple.fruits.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\All Plants Names\AllReports\
```

Is there a way to access it without using the word @SSL\DavWWWRoot?

Another note:

Webclient is running fine. No issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I post on MS Q&A: [Accessing SharePoint 2019 folders using UNC issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159278/accessing-sharepoint-2019-folders-using-unc-issue), as per my knowledge it is not supported to access SharePoint 2019 library using UNC path if you don't map the library to a network drive. This is by design. You can submit your feedback to MS here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. Customer feedback is very important to us – your ideas can change and improve products for users around the world.